# Question on showing continuity

Tags: general-topology, continuity, homotopy-theory

I have $Y$ any convex subspace of $\Bbb{R}^n$ and $I = [0,1]$.

I define $f : Y\times I \rightarrow Y$ as

$f(y,t) = (1-t)y$

Then how can I show that $f$ is continuous?

Let $S$ be any open set in $Y$. How can I say that its inverse image is open in $Y \times I$?

Comment: Nothing wrong with starting with the general definition, but it is helpful to think of the simpler definition of continuity. e.g The function is defined at (a,b) and its limit exists there and the value of the limit is equal to $f(a,b)$.

Comment: $f$ is not well-defined unless $0 \in Y$.

Comment: @PaulFrost..why?

Comment: Because $0=f(y,1)\in Y$ for some (any) $y\in Y$. Except in the trivial case where $Y$ is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $0 \in Y$. Let $O$ be an open subset of $Y$.
We wish to show that $f^{-1}(O) = \left\{(y, t) \in Y \times I: f(y, t) \in O\right\}$ is an open subset of $Y \times I$.

If $(y, t) \in f^{-1}(O)$, then $f(y, t) = (1-t)y \in O$ for all $0 \leq t \leq 1$. It follows for $t = 0$ that $y \in O$ and so $(y, t) \in O \times I$, implying $f^{-1}(O) \subset O \times I$.

We can assume that $0 \in O$. Then for any $y \in O$, we have by the convexity of $O$, for any $t \in [0, 1]$, we have $t.0 + (1-t)y \in O$, which implies $f(y, t) \in O$, which implies $(y, t) \in f^{-1}(O)$, implying $O \times I \subset f^{-1}(O)$.

Hence, $f^{-1}(O) = O\times I$, which is open in $Y \times I$.